# Why doesn't `print() && print_r()` output both things?

Tags: php, printing

According to [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/print) you're "not required to use parenthesis" on `print` since it "isn't a real function", but you can still do it to use it as a function, and it *[always returns 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php#refsect1-function.print-returnvalues)*.

So in my code I tried to do this:

`print('<pre>') && print_r($array) && die;`

...and the `<pre>` never got printed out to the page.

Naturally, if I do this:

```
print('<pre>');
print_r($array) && die;
```

...then it's fine.

But how come the first doesn't work?

Comment: I just tried it, it works! when you say it does not work, did you forget to close the `</pre>` ?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I meant by that, if he waits something visual on the HTML, to apply the code highlight for example, maybe he missed the closing </pre>, I dont know :p

Comment: One thing I don't get though in your code is the `&&` shouldn't be just `print_r($array); die;`

Comment: @teeyo No, what i mean is i don't even see the `<pre>` in the source. If you do `$array = array('a', 'b');print('<pre>') && print_r($array) && die;`, the `<pre>` doesn't get output.

Comment: @JayBlanchard You totally replicated it, the `<pre>` didn't get output in your example (which is what my question was about).

Comment: In my local test it output the `<pre>` tag.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Now you're getting weird, because it definitely shouldn't, according to the accepted answer here, and the additional explanation on the official documentation that i unfurtunately missed, it absolutely shouldn't output the `<pre>`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php#85310

Comment: OK - it's not weird. I, when typing in the code myself, typed the correct parentheses without paying attention. I did not copy and paste your code, which doesn't work and what I did in the sandbox I linked to earlier. I need more coffee.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print` is not a function but a language construct. The parentheses have no real meaning to it. What is really getting executed is:

```
print (('<pre>' && print_r($array)) && die);
```

It's first evaluating the `'<pre>'`, which is truthy, and then proceeds to evaluating the `print_r` call, which prints something to screen, and then tries to combine that with `die`, which kills the script. It then never gets around to completing the `&&` expression and `print`ing its result.

If you want to influence the precedence of a `print` call correctly, you need to take the entire thing as one expression:

```
(print '<pre>') && print_r($array) && die;
```